# Error part of loading array from text file does not work correctly

Tags: java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class readfile{
    static int[] array1 = new int[5];
    
    public static int[] choosefile(){
    try {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
                                                            
        int i = 0;
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            array1[i++] = s.nextInt();
        }

        s.close();
        
        
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("The file does not exist!");
        
    }
    return array1;
    }
    
    readfile(int[] array1) { 
        readfile.array1 = array1;
        }
    
    void printarray() {
        System.out.println("Datas in the array");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1));
        System.out.println();
    
    }
```

Basically the code works if the text file exists but if it doesnt the output is like

The file does not exist!
Datas in the array
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

It says "The file does not exist!" but still do other operations with an array whichs all values are 0. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You return *after* the **try catch**. Meaning it hits the catch and then returns array1.
To fix this, you can return inside the catch.

```
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("The file does not exist!");
            //return here
}
```

Edit:
This works:

There has to be something else you are doing in other parts of your code. The ReadFile.choosefile() works fine.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Readfile r1 = new Readfile();
    r1.choosefile();

  }
}

class Readfile{
    static int[] array1 = new int[5];
    public static int[] choosefile(){
    try {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
        int i = 0;
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            array1[i++] = s.nextInt();
        }
        s.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("The file does not exist!");
        return array1;
    }
    return array1;
    }
    void readfile(int[] array1) {
        Readfile.array1 = array1;
        }

    void printarray() {
        System.out.println("Datas in the array");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1));
        System.out.println();

    }
 }
```

[image]

Comment: I tried it but its does not working

Comment: That's weird. it works fine at my end. Are there any more code that you are not showing us?

Comment: Okey I made it, There was a little misunderstanding from my side. Thanks for your code it helped.